# URL button in lightning to prepopulate Recordtype doesn't work

Tags: lightning, custom-button, url

I am trying to create URL List button so that I can add it to the related list to auto select record type when button is clicked. But every time it is selecting default record-type no matter which id I pass. below is my URL code

one/one.app#/sObject/temp__c/new?RecordType=012r00000005yDf

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible in Lightning. As an alternative, you can use a Quick Action in Parent Object instead of the New Button in Related List.

Create a Quick Action for the child objct in the Parent Object. Here Model is my Parent object and Device is the child object.

[image]

Add the Quick Action on the Parent Object Page Layout. Remove the New Button from Related List and force User to use the Quick Action Instead. This will open the Record Create page of the child object with the preselected Record Type.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try `recordTypeId=012r00000005yDf` instead of `RecordType=012r00000005yDf`. This should work if you want to use a custom button instead of a quick action.

Comment: This answer is missing explanation about _how_ this should make a difference. Salesforce, in general, is case-insensitive.

Comment: @DerekF, there's more than a case adjustment there (though I agree that some explanation would be valuable). In my case I'm already using the suggested key name.